# Behaviour of gas present in space

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Can we model the hydrogen gas present in space as an ideal gas? If so, can the cooling of space from the big bang obey the ideal gas law? And what would be the pressure of such a gas?

Comment: The ideal gas law does not describe a process but the relation between parameters in a given state.  What do you have in mind when you say "ideal gas law"?

Comment: I think OP is asking if the H2 gas in space is an ideal gas, and therefore can we use $PV=RT$ to describe it.

Comment: @nasu my question is, does the hydrogen in space act like an ideal gas?

Comment: Ideal gas law can be even applied to a collection of galaxies... It will depend on the scale and the phenomenon you are after. Certainly you can retain that expanding gas cool down, and this is true even when a gas is not ideal.

Comment: I guess that you mean "ideal gas at equilibrium". If this is the case, the answer is that it is not at equilibrium.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we model the hydrogen gas present in space as an ideal gas?

One of the criteria for an ideal gas is the molecules need to be far enough apart so that intermolecular forces can be ignored. Certainly in space between stars and planets any hydrogen molecules would be far enough apart to consider the gas ideal. What's more, in the atmospheres of stars and planets, it appears the ideal gas law is a pretty good approximation. See [https://web.njit.edu/~gary/321/Lecture7.html](https://web.njit.edu/%7Egary/321/Lecture7.html)

Hope this helps.